# PHP: register_shutdown_function does not always work with Symfony 2

Tags: php, error-handling, symfony

I'm trying to 'catch' PHP Fatal errors with register_shutdown_function, just so that I can return a clean error message.

In a simple PHP file, both test cases below are correctly handled and my custom 500 error is returned.

```
register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');

//Test Case #1
$nullVar = null;
$nullVar->test();

//Test case #2
$uninitialisedVar->test();


function handleShutdown()
{
$error = error_get_last();
if ($error !== NULL)
{
    ob_clean();
    header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo 'Something bad happened';
}
}
```

However, when using the same mechanism from within a Symfony 2 action inside a controller, test case #2 is not handled anymore: my handler is only called when the variable has been initialised before. However, in both cases we are dealing with the same kind of fatal error (call to a member method on a non-object).

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debug mode Symfony2 calls `set_error_handler` which may be conflicting with the `register_shutdown_function`. In production mode it will not happen.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I'm still confused though... I debugged through Symfony2's handler in ErrorHandler.php and for both my test cases above, the error is handled the same way; but my own handler catches only one of them